# .htaccess rewrite to lowercase

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In my .htaccess I have this rule which works perfectly:

```
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)$ search.php?s=$1    [QSA,L]
```

Now I would force the requested param ($1) to be converted in lowercase. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include next line into your virtual host configuration:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

Including it in your `.htaccess` file won't work.

Then add your rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)$ index.php?s=${lc:$1}    [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, there are no chanches if I've no access to apache configuration?

Comment: You can redirect to an intermediate script (let's say a PHP script) that will do another redirect with url lowercased.

Comment: This is what I will do!